# Problem in solving a differential equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, work

This was a question on my exam that stumped me! I think I got lost in the maths. I really want to know how to solve this, because it is very simple.

**Question**:

A mass $m$ goes up an incline which is at angle $\theta$. It experiences linear drag $\vec{F_{\text{drag}}}=-~b\vec{v}$ as well as gravitational force. If it starts at the bottom with velocity $v$:

(a) How far up the slope does it go?

(b) What is the work done by drag, $W_{\text{drag}}$, and gravity $W_g$ on the mass $m$?

**My attempt**:
$$\sin\theta =\frac{-~mg\vec{y}}{F_g\vec{v}}$$

$$F_{\text{total}}=m \times \frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=-~bv-\frac {mg}{\sin\theta}$$
$$\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\frac{bv}{m}-\frac {g}{\sin\theta}$$
Setting $F_{\text{drag}}$ equal to $F_{\text{gravity}}$ is terminal velocity.
$$F_{\text{drag(y)}}=F_g\vec{y}$$
$$-~bv\sin\theta=-~mg$$
$$V_{\text{term}}=\frac{mg}{b\sin\theta}$$

Plug this value into equation above:

$$\frac{-~bv}{m}=\frac{b\sin\theta}{mg} \times \frac{gv}{\sin\theta}$$
$$\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=\left[-\frac{1}{V_{\text{term}}} \times \frac{gv}{\sin\theta}\right]-\frac {g}{\sin\theta}$$
$$\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=g~\left[\frac{v}{\sin\theta~ {V_{\text{term}}}}-\frac {1}{\sin\theta}\right]$$
So I separate variables(This is where I'm super unsure about my math):
$$\left[\frac{\sin\theta~ {V_{\text{term}}}}{v}- {\sin\theta}\right]~\mathrm{d}v=g \ \mathrm{dt}$$
Integrating to get:
$${\sin\theta~ {V_{\text{term}}}} \times \ln(v)-\sin\theta~ v= gt$$

Then I realized that I was completely lost. Because I'm looking for height, not time or velocity! I wanted to perform a change in variables, but it didn't really work:

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac {\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} \times v$$

Then I ran out of time. And didn't even attempt B - which is even more complicated.

Could somebody show the right way to solve (a)?

Comment: See [this](http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com//?qa=193/problem-in-solving-differential-equation) Physics Problems Q&A question.

Answer (score 1):

The component of the weight down the slope is $mg \sin \theta$ not $\frac{mg}{\sin \theta}$.
There is no terminal speed as the mass goes up the incline, stops, and then comes down again.

So you have your differential equation $\frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\frac{bv}{m}- g\sin\theta$ which you need to solve.

Rather than change variables I think it might be easier to stick to solving this equation.

If you are unsure about how to solve it plug **solve[v'[t]=-a*v[t]-b]** into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5Bv%27%5Bt%5D%3D-a*v%5Bt%5D-b%5D).

The constant of integration you can find by setting the intitial velocity at time $t=0$.

The time for maximum height $t_{\rm max}$ you can find by setting $v=0$.

You can then integrate your velocity equation to find the distance travelled along the slope before the velocity becomes zero.

The second part is perhaps easier than you think in that you can find the work done by the gravitational field on the mass by using the distance moved along the slope to find the vertical height achieved.
You can then do the same thing but assuming that there was no frictional force.
The difference is the work done on the mass by the frictional force.

Answer (score 0):

The equations of motions you've written aren't correct. Maybe it's better to sketch a force diagram for the mass and solve it in directions parallel and orthogonal to the surface of the slope. Then you can use the change in variable you've mentioned in the last equation to find the distance.